# Salesforce Marketing Cloud custom activity - wait for API trigger

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I'm new to Custom activities so I'm not sure if my scenario is even possible but..

Let's say I have a Journey and it starts with a simple email out message, the customer receives the email and then clicks a link to a video, they watch the video and on completing the video I want to then let JB know the execution path to take.. "COMPLETED" or "NOT_COMPLETED".

My understanding is if a custom activity is placed let's say after the message "email" activity the custom activity will execute even before a customer has a chance to read their email.

Is there a way for JB to wait until an API call is made to trigger the custom activity?

So the workflow would be 
[Email]-> [WaitForTrigger]-> [CustumActivity]-> [OutCome]-> [ExitActivity]

Hope this is clear.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vinnie, does your chosen video player send a “completed” event when the viewer completes the video?

Comment: Yeah it does Cameron.

Comment: Great! Will you be embedding the video on a Cloud Page, or will it be viewed on a 3rd party site (and the complete tag can be triggered with a Tag Management solution like GTM?)

Comment: The video will be on a third party website so it will have to trigger MC via API. I'm not to sure what you mean by Tag Management or GTM?

Comment: GTM is Google Tag Manager. If the 3rd party website allows you to trigger Rest/Soap APIs, then you can use the DataEvents REST API to update a field in the Journey DE; then use the “wait by attribute” activity in Journey Builder to wait until the user has completed the video. If the 3rd party website does not allow you to use Rest APIs (so your API code is hidden from the end user), then you may need to look at another solution, such as a tracking pixel.

Comment: Cameron you're a legend the "wait by attribute" is exactly what I'm after. Once I get a working version going I'll post an update for anyone else needing this type of solution

Comment: The wait by attribute end date doesn’t update once the contact hits the wait activity. So if it’s not set or changes after they entered the wait step they will still leave at the original time

Comment: EazyE is correct, my mistake. A normal Wait activity for an hour or so followed by a decision split might work for you.